# Is there any built in flutter library for 2D bar-code scanner?

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I am developing a mobile application with Flutter framework and I want to scan bill bar-code and extract its code, so I need a bar-code scanner library for my app. Actually I've googled and found some libraries and SDKs, but they are not written in Dart and I have to import and implement them separately for Android and iOS directories, also it has lots of effort for me to import native codes to a Flutter project. Now I have following questions:
Is there any Dart written and Flutter compatible package, library, SDk, API or ... to use in Flutter project?
Hasn't Google made Flutter version of its ML-KIT or Google-Vision SDKs for its own multi platform framework?
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct flutter widgets available which supports Barcode reading as of now.
Anyway you can use `firebase_ml_vision` plugin which pretty straight forward and easy to integrate.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision

Comment: this plugin is still very very unstable and easily crashes on any OS

Answer (score 0):

There is, but I haven't ever used it myself. Just searched it on here: https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan or maybe this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_flutter

Comment: These are not direct flutter widgets. These are plugins provided by third party developers.  @Aditya Nigam

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN I know, but this is a plugin that might work. Third party or not, we just need working code.

Comment: And this is what the question says "Actually I've googled and found some libraries and SDKs, but they are not written in Dart and I have to import and implement them separately for Android and iOS directories" ... "Is there any Dart written and Flutter compatible package". Just saying.

Comment: Is there a library for android that is not written with Kotlin at least?

Comment: @MohsenEmami I don't know about any of that. And the instructions within the links are quitte clear.